# How to use c++ to display unicode supplementary charactor ( > U+FFFF) in console app in Windows 10? (without winrt if possible)

Tags: c++, winapi, utf-8, utf-16, windows-console

It seems USC2 characters are okey with `wchar_t`.
However when a codepoint is more than `U+FFFF`, it just doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

int main()
{
  _setmode( _fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT ); // _O_WTEXT has no difference
  std::wcout.sync_with_stdio(false);
  std::wcout << L"z\u00df\u6c34\U0001F34C\n" << std::endl;  // L"zß水"
}
```

Print as below:

```
zß水�
```

How to print SMP characters on console app in Windows?
Is it possible without `C++/WinRT`?

Comment: Does the font you are using to display the console have that glyph?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I just tried the new Windows Terminal. `'zß水' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` when enter `zß水`. However app above still doesn't work.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using [`_O_U16TEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=vs-2019)?

Comment: @IInspectable Just tried it and output is `zß水��`

Comment: That's a limitation with Windows console. `` won't show properly even if you copy/paste it directly in to console. Changing the console font doesn't make a difference either. That's probably a limitation relating to `0xffff` as you have suggested.

Comment: Seems that Barmak is correct, see [here](https://rextester.com/EDQOA64147)

Comment: Windows Terminal will be the replacement for the existing console (conhost.exe). [It  should support emoji](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/190). [There is a preview in the Windows Store](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-microsoft-store-preview-release/).

Comment: [windows console doesn't really support UTF-16](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/235cbbe4d8087ebd62dd9271a4d585458ffed45a/deps/uv/src/win/tty.c#L2063-L2068)

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Windows Terminal will land on December 2019. Do you think that this new conhost will be part of v2003 next spring?

Comment: Not sure, but you can follow up their updates on this [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal).